# Timpani Choke Notation

Tags: notation, percussion, band, timpani

I'm writing a timpani part for a concert band score. I've seen timpanist "choke" the note with their hand (on the head) after striking it to stop it from sustaining. How can I notate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the length of note you want.  If you want notes separated by rests, write them.  The timpanist will damp as necessary.

Comment: Or write them as staccato.

Comment: I'm unconvinced - there's gotta be a difference between damping a note and letting it ring.

Comment: Certainly there is.  That's why we have note-lengths, rests and the l.v. instruction.

Comment: Also, a tie to nowhere means to mean let ring

Comment: A 'tie to nowhere' IS one form of the l.v. instruction.  The other is the text 'l.v.'

Comment: "why we have note-lengths..."  But at least for non-percussion instruments, the end of the note indicates to stop **producing** the note, not to damp resonances.

Comment: You feel all percussion is 'l.v.' by default?

Answer (score 0):

There are several symbols at my [favorite reference](https://www.dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm)   such as "+" which indicate percussion instrument damping.  I plead ignorance as to which symbols are applied to the tympani in particular.  Search the linked page for the word "damp," and you'll see a couple crosshair-like symbols, sadly without comments as to applicability.